# iOS Calendar, how can I change the text on the notification center

Tags: ios, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I'm trying my luck on a calendar app, I'm giving the possibility for users to add an alarm ahead of the actual event time, (5 min, 15 min, 1 hour, a day ... before).

In the `UILocalNotification` class reference, I find the `NSDate` Property (`fireDate`), which is the time the notification is sent and seen on the notification center if the app is closed or in background the moment of the `fireDate`, the local notification takes an `alertAction`/`alertBody` etc.

If I take the iOS calendar app and create an event with a reminder an hour ahead, when the notification is seen in the notification center, it's body keeps updating:

```
New event in 59 min

New event in 58 min

New event in 57 min...
```

Is this behavior a custom implementation (how can it be done), or am I missing something obvious, like a `fireDate`, and `actualFireDate` kind of thing.

Comment: Apple apps do things that other apps can't do.  This is one of those things

Comment: @Paulw11 I see, thanks for the reply.